# Help identify instrument from Hateful Eight

Tags: identify-this-instrument

In the movie Hateful Eight by Quentin Tarantino there is a recurring theme played by a low-sounding brass instrument. You can hear it in [this piece](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKQxJV5yX-A).

Is this a kind of tuba or horn?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm tempted to say [contrabassoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrabassoon), as the instrument playing the seriously low D starting in the 2nd bar. For the rest of that phrase, I'd be hard-pressed to distinguish whether it was [bassoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bassoon) or contra-

The later section starting 0.46, I'd definitely go for contra- with what may be tuba above it.

I found this quote from Morricone, reported by the [BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-35042217)

> The main instruments introducing this piece are the bassoon, the contra-bassoon and the tuba,

Comment: That's a contrabassoon, for certain!  As my sister would like to say: they have two dynamics, on and off, and sound kind of like a chainsaw.